# Open location shared URL from Apple maps or google maps in to custom ios application?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, maps, sharing

I need to give "OPEN In My App" option whenever a location is shared from google maps or apple maps just like whatsapp feature. i have added the screen shot as well, please guide.

[image]